# android screen resolution

Tags: android, screen

I am developing the application for " Samsung GT-S5830 mobile " and "samsung galxy s5360".
Can any one suggest me.What will the resolution or dpi is applicable for the android application?

I want to know "what config should i select for our application? like "2.7in Qvca"in eclipse our any custom we have to use .then what should be x and y".

Comment: Does anyone know a single source for information of this type across common devices - such a collection would be an asset to the community.

Comment: i dont understand the question. Why not simply google the data sheets for those devices? Wikipedia also has a comprehensive list of device specs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for galaxy ace HVGA(320X480) and for galaxy y QVGA(240X320) . and make Layout-normal-ldpi and put your xmls into it for designing..